# batchquery in google drive sdk using objective c

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, google-api-objc-client

How to create a batchquery in google drive sdk using objective c? I have already created single queries, and I wonder how to get responses from batchquery as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a GTLBatchQuery object and add queries to it, then execute the batch query. A GTLBatchResult is passed to the callback.  Individual queries can have their own completion handler blocks as well.

There is an example batch request in the docs [here.](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/wiki/Introduction#Batch_Operations)